# Connect mobile phone with home network

Tags: openvpn

I want to connect my mobile phone via OpenVPN with my home network for two reasons: first I want to access multiple services at home from my mobile phone. And second the phone should use the home's internet for security reasons in open wireless networks.

Because my router has no public IP address a Raspberry Pi in the home network shall connect as client with a OpenVPN server with a public address (a root server I own).

So I want to accomplish the following network:

[image: Link to image]

I got it so far that the VPN-Server, the Raspberry and the mobile phone can communicate with each other (ping and services). But I didn't get the connection to the home LAN or the internet through the home router to work.

These are my configs:

The home network is 192.168.2.0, the VPN is 10.8.0.0.

Server:

```
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ./easy-rsa2/keys/ca.crt
cert ./easy-rsa2/keys/server.crt
key ./easy-rsa2/keys/server.key
dh ./easy-rsa2/keys/dh2048.pem
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
client-to-client
push "route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0"
client-config-dir ccd
route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0

user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
```

Raspberry:

```
client
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
remote example.com 1194
nobind
ca ca.crt
cert pi.crt
key pi.key
ns-cert-type server
remote-cert-tls server
push "route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0"
route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0

persist-key
persist-tun
resolv-retry infinite
```

Raspberry in ccd:

```
iroute 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0
```

Phone:

```
client
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
remote example.com 1194
nobind
ca ca.crt
cert phone.crt
key phone.key
ns-cert-type server
remote-cert-tls server
route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0

persist-key
persist-tun
resolv-retry infinite
```

How could one accomplish such a project? Or at least the two things above with another setup?

**Edit**: I figured out the problem: The ccd folder has to be on the server side, not the client...
Even if i have a slightly different solution now, this should also solve the problem for this setup.

Comment: Your home devices (192.x) will not communicate with your phone (10.x), because they have no idea that they should route these packets to Raspberry instead of their default gateway (192.168.2.1). You have 4 options: 1) get rid of 10.x, bridge vpn devices into your 192.x subnet 2) set up custom routes to 10.x on your home devices 3) do srcnat 10.x->192.x on raspberry 4) connect all home devices to 10.x vpn

Comment: And how do I do that?
The first option seems to be the easiest one, right?

Comment: @BenediktMagnus FYI: your configs are missing pertinent security parameters, rendering your VPN susceptible to MITM attacks [`auth SHA512` if x64 CPUs are used, else `auth SHA256`, and `tls-crypt tc.psk`], and SSL failover cipher [`cipher aes-128-cbc`] isn't specified; also missing are options for performance [`tun-mtu 48000` and possibly `sndbuf` & `rcvbuf`], and logging [server: `verb 5` | client: `verb 4`] _([example](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/tree/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenVPN) configs)_. For efficiency, server firewall should allow TCP & UDP on the VPN port for troubleshooting

Comment: @Sergei An OpenVPN bridge setup [TAP - layer 2] should [only](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/some-basic-networking-concepts-simplified/#osi-layer-2-bridging-and-layer-3-routing) be used when a router is the client - if the router is not, TUN [layer 3] should always be used.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is **not** the one you posted in your Edit, though that was absolutely necessary for your setup to work. The *real* problem has been correctly diagnosed by *@Sergei*, but there is a much simpler way to implement it: add a route to the outside client, the phone, thru the raspberry, **on the router**.

You said you are using *ccd*, thus the phone will have a static internal IP address, say *10.8.0.55*. Then **on the router** add the following route:

```
ip route add 10.8.0.55/32 via Raspberry.Pi.IP.Address
```

if the OpenVPN server is **not** hosted by the raspberry, or

```
ip route add 10.8.0.0/24 via Raspberry.Pi.IP.Address
```

if the server is on the rasp pi.

The difference between the two commands is that in the first case only the phone can be reached via the rasp pi, hence the route is for the single client accessible thru it, while in the second command the whole OpenVPN network can be reached via the rasp pi.

This is simpler because you only need to modify **one** component, the router, not all the individual machines in your network.

And, BTW, the first solution suggested by Sergei is **emphatically not** the simplest one, since it involves switching from a routed to a bridged OpenVPN, not just using the home network for the OpenVPN subnet as you seem to believe.

That`s all.

Comment: That's totally right. I forgot to mention that I added a static route to the network on my router. Thanks for bringing that up.

Comment: An OpenVPN bridge setup [TAP - layer 2] should [only](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/some-basic-networking-concepts-simplified/#osi-layer-2-bridging-and-layer-3-routing) be used when a router is the client - if the router is not, TUN [layer 3] should always be used.